# PL SQL Function while loop ending unexpectedly

Tags: sql, function, plsql, while-loop

i have a function where i want to calculate seconds between two dates these seconds should be calculated only in our companys opening hours. because it can take several days for the task to be completed i have created a while loop that should increment the days

here is my loop:

```
    WHILE TO_DATE(TRUNC(dateIterator),'YYYY-MM-DD') < TO_DATE(TRUNC(CallbackUpdatedDate),'YYYY-MM-DD') LOOP
 calculateIntervalFrom := null;
calculateIntervalTo := null;

SELECT THIS_DATE_OPENING,
 THIS_DATE_CLOSING,
 NEXT_DATE_OPENING
INTO thisDateOpening, thisDateClosing, nextDay
FROM KS_DRIFT.SYS_DATE_KS
WHERE THIS_DATE = dateIterator;

-- gets calculated from
calculateIntervalFrom := thisDateOpening;

-- Gets calculateTo
IF dateIterator = TO_DATE(TRUNC(CallbackUpdatedDate),'YYYY-MM-DD') THEN
calculateIntervalTo := CallbackUpdatedDate;
ELSE
calculateIntervalTo := thisDateClosing;
END IF;
fromSeconds := abs(extract(second from TO_TIMESTAMP(calculateIntervalFrom))) + extract(minute from TO_TIMESTAMP(calculateIntervalFrom)) * 60 + extract(hour from TO_TIMESTAMP(calculateIntervalFrom)) * 60 * 60;
toSeconds :=abs(extract(second from TO_TIMESTAMP(calculateIntervalTo))) + extract(minute from TO_TIMESTAMP(calculateIntervalTo)) * 60 + extract(hour from TO_TIMESTAMP(calculateIntervalTo)) * 60 * 60;
intervalDifference := fromSeconds - toSeconds;

solvedSeconds := solvedSeconds + intervalDifference;
dateIterator := nextDay;
dbms_output.put_line(nextDay);
```

**A small explanation**

So The idea is that as long as the value `dateIterator` (which is the date of which the row is created) is not the same as last time the row was updated (`CallbackUpdatedDate`) it will select today and the next daysopening hours from the table `KS_DRIFT.SYS_DATE_KS`

If the day today is the same as the `CallbackUpdatedDate` it will set the `calculateIntervalTo` equal to the `CallbackUpdatedDate` else it will set the value to `thisDateClosing`

it will then calculate the seconds between the two dates and add them to the `NUMBER` `solvedSeconds`

After that i will set `dateIterator` to the next opening day: `dateIterator := nextDay;`

This works but only twice and then it simply ends the loop:

Here is the two dates it trys to compute:

Created: 2013-03-26 10:23:33

Last updated: 2013-04-03 09:25:10

```
dbms_output.put_line(nextDay); outputs these two values:
```

2013-03-27 and
2013-03-27

By the looks of it, it would seem that the SELECT statement within the while loop does not work as intended but i simply cannot see why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks strange how you treat the dates:

```
TO_DATE(TRUNC(dateIterator),'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

So dateIterator is a date which you trunc, i.e. you remove the time part. This gives you a date with time set to 00:00:00. But then you use the to_date function on that date as if it were a string. This looks wrong to me.

Then in your select statement you have

```
WHERE THIS_DATE = dateIterator
```

and I wonder: Above you had to strip the time from dateIterator. Here you don't. Does your table have entries for the dateIterator incuding the time part?

I hope these findings already help solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a WHILE loop, why not just use a single query? Something like:

```
select (end_date - start_date - 
        (select coalesce(sum(least(NEXT_DATE_OPENING,end_date) -
                             greatest(THIS_DATE_CLOSING,start_date)),0)
         from KS_DRIFT.SYS_DATE_KS
         where THIS_DATE_CLOSING < end_date and 
               NEXT_DATE_OPENING > start_date)) * 86400 available_time
from dual
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/72435/7).